# Using (void*) as a type of an identifier

Tags: c++, identity, strict-aliasing

In my program, I have objects (of the same class) that must all have a unique identifier. For simplicity and performance, I chose to use the address of the object as identifier. And to keep the types simple, I use `(void*)` as a type for this identifier. In the end I have code like this:

```
class MyClass {
public:
  typedef void* identity_t;
  identity_t id() const { return (void*)this; }
}
```

This seems to be working fine, but gcc gives me a strict-aliasing warning. I understand the code would be bad if the id was used for data transfer. Luckily it is not, but the question remains: will aliasing optimisations have an impact on the code produced? And how to avoid the warning?

Note: I am reluctant to use `(char*)` as this would imply the user can use the data for copy, which it can not!

Comment: Could you post the full text of the warning? Thanks.

Comment: No cast is necessary to convert to void *, as this is one of the standard C++ conversions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are violating logical constness returning the object as mutable in a const method.
As Neil points out, no cast is needed.

```
class MyClass {
public:
  typedef const void* identity_t;
  identity_t id() const { return this; }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try using the type `uintptr_t` instead of `void*`.  `uintptr_t` is a integer type that is defined as being big enough to hold any pointer value.  And since it's not actually a pointer, the compiler won't flag any aliasing problems.

```
class MyClass {
public:
    typedef uintptr_t identity_t;
    identity_t id() const { return (identity_t)this; }
}
```

Comment: There is no `uintptr_t` in C++. It's C99 (and possibly C++0x).

Comment: Surprisingly, using `uintptr_t` leads to the following warning:

warning: dereferencing pointer ‘__x.939’ does break strict-aliasing rules

Comment: @Zach: your code keeps the logical constness violation error.

Comment: @avakar True, but g++ seems to handle the type just fine :)

Comment: @PierreBdR I'm not getting that warning when I compile this code.  Maybe you're getting the error somewhere else in your program (are you casting the uintptr_t back to a MyClass*)?

Comment: @fnieto What advantage does static_cast give in this case, other than purity?  Can you give an example of using static_cast to cast const MyClass *const to uintptr_t?

Comment: @Zach: the advantage is that it is a C++ cast. The tag of the question es C++, not mixed C/C++. Same apply to avakar advise, in spite your C++ compiler executes with C support by default.

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
return static_cast<void*>(this);
```

This should be perfectly safe, any pointer should be able to be cast to `void *` without risk of loss.

I originally suggested `dynamic_cast(this);`, but after reading up a bit I think it adds no advantage, and since it's RTTI-only it's not a good solution in general.

By the way, I would make the returned value `const`, since the identity of an object cannot change.

Comment: What advantage does using `dynamic_cast` instead of plain simple `static_cast` have in this case?

Comment: The difference is that the dynamic cast will result in a pointer to the most derived class of `this`, whereas the C-style cast will just reinterpret `this` as void*. I'm not sure whether that's an advantage or not. Btw, you can't dynamic_cast to void* in the example in the question, because MyClass is not a polymorphic type.

Comment: @avakar: None, it seems. I changed it so my second suggestion, which was static_cast<>(), became the primary. :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any aliasing issues. However, you are casting away constness (since the `id` function is const), which the compiler might be unhappy about. Perhaps it'd be better to use `const void*` as your ID type.

Alternatively, cast the address to an integer type such as `size_t`. Then it is no longer a pointer, and aliasing becomes a non-issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using type `MyClass *`?

Or type `intptr_t`?

Comment: intptr_t didn't exist in C++ last I checked. And I assume the ID's have to be comparable between different classes, so `MyClass*` wouldn't work either.